# Consulta de acuerdo las categorías seleccionadas - Eloquent Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, orm

como podría hacer una consulta con Eloquent.
El chiste es de que un usuario

Primero tiene estas categorías que le interesan

```
A)
B)
C)
```

Digamos que esas son las 3 que le interesan. ¿Cómo es posible hacer la consulta?

supongamos que este es mi modelo

```
Ventas

$información = ventas::where()???<- Que haría aqui?
```

¿cómo comparo esas 3 condiciones?

Y que tal si con el tiempo le interesan otras 3 categorías más

```
 D)
 X)
 G)
```

para obtener información de acuerdo sus intereses.

suponiendo que mi tabla de migración es así.

```html
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('ventas', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');

            $table->string('nombre',50);
            $table->string('descripcion',150);

            $table->enum('status',['DETENIDO','PUBLICADO'])->default('DETENIDO');

            $table->integer('categoria_id')
            ->unsigned();

            $table->integer('user_id')
            ->unsigned();

            $table->foreign('categoria_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('categorias')
            ->onDelete('cascade')
            ->onUpdate('cascade');

            $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade')
            ->onUpdate('cascade');


            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

De esa forma según cada  venta, pertenece a una categoría.

espero poder darme a entender

Comment: explica por favor de mejor manera que deseas obtener, esa consulta que tratas de hacer en Eloquent ¿cómo la harías en SQL puro? ese pudiera ser un excelente punto de partida para ayudarte

Comment: Si los identificadores de las categorías que le interesan las tienes en un array: Ventas::whereIn('categoria_id', arrayCategorias)->get()

Comment: @JaviMollá perfecto ahora de hecho ya funciona. me estab rompiendo la cabeza, porque si pensaba hacerlo con un for. pero sabía que hay mejores cosas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta con esto:

```
$filtros = collect([]);

$filtros->put($categoria_A,'Ejemplo_A');
$filtros->put($categoria_B,'Ejemplo_B');
$filtros->put($categoria_C,'Ejemplo_C');

$modelo = $tu_modelo_de_ventas;

$sql = $modelo->whereIn('tu_campo',$filtros->toArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

Con la poca información que nos das, lo que necesitas hacer es esto:

```
$información = ventas::whereIn('campo',['A','B','C'])->get();
```